# How to do further calculations on a new subtracted data frame in python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a data frame in python. I subtract a new data frame, named newdf, from the base data frame, named df, and want to do some calculations on the new data frame.
I try the code below, but python does the calculations on the basic data frame yet!

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/narge/Desktop/Site 1.csv')
newdf = df.loc[df['Class Name'] == 'F6']
df = pd.DataFrame(newdf)
for i in range (len(df)):
Column=df['Axle Weights (kg)'][i]
Separated_Column=Column.split('|')
Separated_Axle_Weights=list(map(float,Separated_Column))
print(Separated_Axle_Weights)
```

I expect to see the separated values of Axle Weights (kg) column for the new data frame which include only the F6 class Names.
Below is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/narge/PycharmProjects/GDOT_WIM/Clustering.py", line 50, in <module>
    tmp=df['Axle Weights (kg)'][i]
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4375, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 987, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 993, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have you tried doing `df[i]['Axle Weights (kg)']` instead of what you're currently doing (the reverse of that)?

Comment: why this is marked [tag:pycharm]?

Comment: I should say that when I try to subtract the new data frame the code works (up to line 8). Also, when I try to split the column values (running code in lines 9 to 13) the code does answer. However, I get the above error when I relate two parts of the code!

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I just tried. Does not work!

Comment: @Tomerikoo I work in Pycharm. However, no difference.

Comment: As this doesn't present a specific issue or problem related to `PyCharm`, it is not necessary

Comment: Can you paste how dataframe looks like?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide some sample input and output so we can better understand your issue and help